# how to set radio button text(caption) to center

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

***VB.NET 2010 , ASPNET* *********

Hi,

Is there a way to set the radio button text to center, 
I want to show it on the top of radiobutton hole..thanks

Answer (score 2):

The text and the radio button are separate, so you can style them any way you like. Example:

HTML:

```
<label class="CenteredRadio">
  <span>Click me</span>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="yes" />
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.CenteredRadio { width: 300px; }
.CenteredRadio span { display: block; text-align: center; }
.CenteredRadio input { display: block; text-align: center; }
```

If you are using a `RadioButton` control, set it's text to an empty string, and you can use your own text.

Comment: @spy: The `RadioButton` control only supports placing the text to the left or to the right of the button. Anything outside of that means that you have to do the layout yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Text` of the `RadioButton` to `String.Empty`. Add a `Label` to the top of it.